# Icarus Verilog warning $readmemh: Standard inconsistency, following 1364-2005

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I'm trying to read a memory file using `$readmemh`, but I'm not sure what the correct file format is since I'm seeing a warning.

In my testbench, I have the following:

```
reg [7:0] progmem [4095:0];

initial begin
    $readmemh("progmem.txt", progmem);
end
```

And `progmem.txt` contains:

```
01
03
ff
00
```

and so on for a total of 4096 rows. When running the testbench, `vvp` displays:

```
$readmemh: Standard inconsistency, following 1364-2005
```

I have tried looking this up, but I haven't found an explanation as to what that actually means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different versions of the IEEE Std 1364 specify how memories are loaded via `$readmemh` differently.

1364-1995 states:

> ... the default start address is the **left-hand address** given in the
> declaration of the memory. Consecutive words are loaded until either
> the memory is full ...

1364-2001 states:

> ... the default start address shall be the **lowest address** in the
> memory. Consecutive words shall be loaded until either the highest
> address in the memory is reached ...

In your declaration, the left-hand address is 4095, but the lowest address is 0.

Instead of loading the 1st word (01) into `progmem[4095]`, I believe the warning is telling you that it is loading the 1st word into `progmem[0]`.

When I change the declaration to the following, the warning disappears for me on `iverilog` on edaplayground:

```
reg [7:0] progmem [0:4095];
```